# Ensure that there are no more than 0 digits before the decimal point

Tags: django, model

When I fill the **bathroom field** in my model with a value like  **1.1, 2.5**  anything with a digit before decimal it shows an error that **no more than 0 digits before decimal point**. If I give a value like **.2, .3** then Django does not show any error. Same problem with the **lot field**.

```
class listing(models.Model):
    realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sqft = models.IntegerField()
    lot_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=2)
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'self.date'
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield):

> For example, to store numbers up to 999 with a resolution of 2 decimal places, you’d use:
>
> - models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

So, if you want up to 9.99 bathrooms, you would use:

```
bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

(I'm not sure why you want a fractional number of toilets, but that's a separate issue...)

Comment: I wanted to try decimalfield so i use any field randomly.